# Unable to measure frequency response of a Wien bridge oscillator with Bode plot

Tags: transistors, ac, oscillator, signal, frequency

I'm unable to get the Bode plot to work with this Wien bridge oscillator circuit.

Is there something wrong with my configuration, or does the Bode plot not work without an external signal source?

I assume that the Bode plotter would theoretically measure the frequency response of the oscillator since it produces a signal.

[image: Wien Bridge Oscillator simulation in NI Multisim]

Comment: An oscillator doesn't have a valid external signal input hence, a bode plot is meaningless

Comment: @Andyaka thank you for your reply. That is what I also thinking lately, I was just looking for confirmation in the internet, and I can't find any. Thank you for confirming it!

Comment: As another view: A working oscillator has a pole on the imag. axis of the s-plane. This is identical with a pole-Q of infinite - corresponding to an infinite gain at the frequency of oscillation. This cannot give any meaningful result. However, when simulating the LOOP GAIN and display it as a Bode plot you can verify the oscillation criterion.

Answer (score 0):

The original of the very old (BC107) schematic is in Google. You copied the resistance of R4 wrong. The highpass/lowpass Wien Bridge has a bandpass at 1kHz. In Google they are at [www.next.gr/](http://www.next.gr/) [www.electroninic.com](http://www.electroninic.com) and [www.blopspot.comm](http://www.blopspot.comm) and probably at many more websites.

[image: Wien]

Here is the bandpass response:

[image: bandpass response]

Comment: Audioguru - Hi, In order for you to comply with [this site rule](/help/referencing), please [edit] your answer to add a proper reference, which names the source & includes a link back to the original web page / PDF file etc. for the "very old" schematic which you included. (Saying that it is "in Google" is not enough.)  Thanks. (After you have done that, please reply in a comment so that I can remove *this* comment.)

Comment: Audioguru - Thanks for editing the answer. However as I said (and as explained in that site rule), the requirement when including material copied from elsewhere, is to provide a link to the source *web page*, not various website home pages. Therefore to comply with that rule, please provide the specific *web page* which was the source for that schematic you copied. Thanks.